# How do I remove random object inside array? New to java

Tags: java

I'm doing a small project where I have two different types of ball objects inside a bag array and I want to take two random objects from that bag. The problem that I am having is removing the objects from that bag array. I am succeeding to take two random objects but it takes in their position in the bag array and I don't really know how to remove objects from that bag array.

```
public class Bag {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Balls whiteBalls = new Balls("White");
        Balls blackBalls = new Balls("Black");
        Balls[] objArray;
        whiteBalls.setAmount(16);
        blackBalls.setAmount(20);
        int totalBalls = whiteBalls.getAmount() + blackBalls.getAmount();
        // Create two arrays that hold white and black balls together.
        Balls[] white = new Balls[whiteBalls.getAmount()];
        Balls[] black = new Balls[blackBalls.getAmount()];
        // Adding white balls into array "white".
        for (int i = 0; i < whiteBalls.getAmount(); i++) {
            white[i] = new Balls("White");
        } // Adding black balls into array "black"
        for (int i = 0; i < blackBalls.getAmount(); i++) {
            black[i] = new Balls("Black");
        }
        Balls[] bag = new Balls[totalBalls]; // Making a bag which holds all the balls.
        // Copy's both arrays and fills up array "bag".
        System.arraycopy(white, 0, bag, 0, whiteBalls.getAmount());
        System.arraycopy(black, 0, bag, 16, blackBalls.getAmount());
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bag));

        int count = 0;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        String[] colours = new String[]{"White", "Black"};

        while(bag.length != 1){ // Depending on what colour the balls are either black ball or       white ball is placed back into the bag.
            count++;
            int select1 = rnd.nextInt(colours.length);
            int select2 = rnd.nextInt(colours.length);
            while(white.length != 0 || black.length != 0){
                if(select1 == 0 && select2 == 0){
                    System.out.println("Both are the same colour. " + select1 + " " + select2);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The other problem that I am running into is in my other class which balls one method 'getColour()' doesn't want to work for some reason.

```
public class Balls {
    private String colour;
    private int amount;

    public Balls(String type) {
        colour = type;
    }

    public String getColour() {
        return colour;

    }

    public void changeAmount(int num){
        this.setAmount(num);
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return colour;

    }
}
```

Any feedback is appreciated. Thank you for reading and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you using an ArrayList, as it provides methods to remove elements from within the list (be aware, as this can be quite costly in a large array). The remove() method can take an index of the object to remove or the object to remove itself, as the method is overloaded. Be aware, as storing to int's that hold the index of the element in the bag that should be removed, can result in unexpected results, as it can be, that this index points to the wrong object after you removed an object after you stored the indices.
So, I hope this answer helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry to bother you again, but I ran into another problem. I conversted arrays to ArrayList everything is working, Now I need to check what object the random method is taking and compare with the other pull. I am not sure how to do that because the random method is pulling the index I'm not sure how to compare them since I set their type to represent each object by it's colour.

`if (select1 = "Black" && select2 = "Black") {`

I'm trying to do this inside while loop. Sadly I don't know how to paste in that code for you. Hopefuly you will have time to get back to me.

Comment: So, I would just get the object instances from your array list with get(). Then, if you want to remove an item, you can just use that very instance. If you want to compare the two colours of the items, I'd not recommend to use select1 == "Black", as it doesn't work. You should rather use select1.equals("Black"), as this compares the content of the string rather then the identities of the variables.